# F# module extension vs type entension

Tags: f#

if I want to define a extension method for float array like standard deviation, would it be better to use module extension on Array module or extension on type `float[]`? 
like :

```
module Array =
   let std (arr: float[]) = ...
```

or

```
type float ``[]`` with 
    member this.std = ...
```

If I do type extension as the latter, would the `std` be only calculated once or every time it is used?

And, what is the right format for  the latter, apprently ``` type float ``[]`` with ``` does not comile... thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you can't define a type extension so the issue is moot - you must use an extension of the `Array` module.  The reason that you can't define a type extension is that in F#, type extensions must exactly mirror type definitions, so you can define a type extension on the generic `'a list` type, for instance, but not on the constructed type `string list`.  Similarly, you could define an extension method on the (simulated) generic array type

```
'a ``[]``
```

but not on the constructed array type

```
float ``[]``
```

This behavior is different than C#, where it is possible to write extension methods on constructed generic types.

Comment: @Daniel - I do not.  However, I think that F#'s behavior does make sense - why shouldn't type extensions mirror type definitions?  Doesn't it seem strange that the methods on an instance of a constructed generic type would depend on its type arguments?

Comment: @kvb: Yes, but it seems to make perfect sense on generic interfaces. E.g., `string Join(this IEnumerable<string> parts)` seems reasonable.

Comment: I think C# and F# extension features are conceptually different, illuminated by their differing syntax. Whereas F# emphasizes the extension of a type definition, C# extensions are implemented as mere static methods and can indeed be called as such (first parameter is marked "this"). Hence, if you are familiar with C# extensions, it makes perfect sense that you'd be able to overload on the "this" parameter. And you tend to think of them as what they are, static methods with instance syntax.

Comment: @Daniel - I think that there are good arguments both ways, I'm just claiming that F#'s approach isn't necessarily deficient.  I think that this is particularly true given the nice alternative of modules in F#.

Comment: It's possible to both consume C# extension methods in F#, and create C#-style extension methods in F# that are consumable by C#. If C#-style extension methods are also consumable in F# (I can't seem to get that part to work) then it might be possible to do what you want that way.

Comment: @Joel - while you can do both of those things, as far as I know you cannot define a C#-style extension method in F# and then actually use it as an extension method in F#, unfortunately.